# R Combine Vectors with Different Row Length

Tags: r

How do I combine vectors with different number or rows into a data frame in R. Here is the example. Each vector has 7 or 9 rows. sourceVersion and device are the additional two rows. I want these included in the data frame and left blank or set to NA for the 7 row vector observations, like I have shown in the table below.

I want the data in a data frame like this.

```
type                                    sourceName              sourceVersion   device                                                                                                          unit    creationDate    startDate       endDate         value
HKQuantityTypeIdentifierFlightsClimbed  Ryan Praskievicz iPhone 9.3.2           <<HKDevice: 0x15a4af3f0>, name:iPhone, manufacturer:Apple, model:iPhone, hardware:iPhone8,1, software:9.3.2>    count   6/2/2016 12:27  6/2/2016 12:09  6/2/2016 12:09  1
HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount       Ryan Praskievicz iPhone                                                                                                                                 count   10/2/2014 8:30  9/24/2014 15:07 9/24/2014 15:07 7
```

This is what I have tried.

```
library(XML)

xmlstr <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <HealthData locale="en_US">
              <ExportDate value="2016-06-02 14:05:23 -0400"/>
              <Me HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth="" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex="HKBiologicalSexNotSet" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBloodType="HKBloodTypeNotSet" HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierFitzpatrickSkinType="HKFitzpatrickSkinTypeNotSet"/>
              <Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount" sourceName="Ryan Praskievicz iPhone" unit="count" creationDate="2014-10-02 08:30:17 -0400" startDate="2014-09-24 15:07:06 -0400" endDate="2014-09-24 15:07:11 -0400" value="7"/> <Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifierFlightsClimbed" sourceName="Ryan Praskievicz iPhone" sourceVersion="9.3.2" device="&lt;&lt;HKDevice: 0x15a4af3f0&gt;, name:iPhone, manufacturer:Apple, model:iPhone, hardware:iPhone8,1, software:9.3.2&gt;" unit="count" creationDate="2016-06-02 12:27:46 -0400" startDate="2016-06-02 12:09:29 -0400" endDate="2016-06-02 12:09:29 -0400" value="1"/> </HealthData>'

xml <- xmlParse(xmlstr)

recordAttribs <- xpathSApply(doc=xml, path="//HealthData/Record",  xmlAttrs)
df <- data.frame(t(recordAttribs))
df
```

This is what I get for the output to the R console

```
      X1
            1 HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount, Ryan Praskievicz iPhone, count, 2014-10-02 08:30:17 -0400, 2014-09-24 15:07:06 -0400, 2014-09-24 15:07:11 -0400, 7                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    X2 
1 HKQuantityTypeIdentifierFlightsClimbed, Ryan Praskievicz iPhone, 9.3.2, <<HKDevice: 0x15a4af3f0>, name:iPhone, manufacturer:Apple, model:iPhone, hardware:iPhone8,1, software:9.3.2>, count, 2016-06-02 12:27:46 -0400, 2016-06-02 12:09:29 -0400, 2016-06-02 12:09:29 -0400, 1
```

Comment: Would [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:lPRvnOOSAgoJ:www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/qpcR/docs/cbind.na+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) do what you're looking for?

Comment: First of all, you are trying to bind rows with different number of columns rather than bind columns with different number of rows. That being said, won't you, in general have a column alignment issue? That is, if one row has fewer columns than another, how do you know which columns are missing unless you can somehow deduce that from the data?

Comment: @aichao It appears that the same two rows are missing - sourceVersion and device.

Comment: @aichao yes the same two rows are missing as warner suggested

Answer (score 2):

The dependency is a little esoteric, but you can do:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(recordAttribs, function(x) data.table(t(x))), fill=TRUE)
```

This will return a `data.table`, which inherits `data.frame`.

```
                                     type              sourceName  unit
1:      HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount Ryan Praskievicz iPhone count
2: HKQuantityTypeIdentifierFlightsClimbed Ryan Praskievicz iPhone count
                creationDate                 startDate                   endDate value
1: 2014-10-02 08:30:17 -0400 2014-09-24 15:07:06 -0400 2014-09-24 15:07:11 -0400     7
2: 2016-06-02 12:27:46 -0400 2016-06-02 12:09:29 -0400 2016-06-02 12:09:29 -0400     1
   sourceVersion
1:            NA
2:         9.3.2
                                                                                                         device
1:                                                                                                           NA
2: <<HKDevice: 0x15a4af3f0>, name:iPhone, manufacturer:Apple, model:iPhone, hardware:iPhone8,1, software:9.3.2>
```

The reason I'm using `data.table` is that it has a smart `rbind` method with a `use.names=TRUE` option that allows rows of unequal length, matches columns on name not position, and fills the missing values with NA.

Simpler example of how `rbind.data.table` works:

```
d1 = data.table(a="foo", b = "bar", c = "baz")
d2 = data.table(b="bar", a = "foo")
rbind(d1, d2) # throws helpful error:  "If instead you need to fill missing columns, use set argument 'fill' to TRUE."
rbind(d1, d2, fill=TRUE)
#      a   b   c
# 1: foo bar baz
# 2: foo bar  NA
```

Comment: this works great thanks! When I try to run the `df <-do.call(rbind, c(lapply(recordAttribs, function(x) data.table(t(x))), fill=TRUE))` section on my full data set `recordAttribs` is a Large list (405677 elements, 464 MB) it takes a long time to run. Any ideas on what to do to improve this with a larger data set?

Comment: @RyanPraskievicz please try `rbindlist` as edited above.  If `lapply` is really dragging you down, you might want to look at `multicore::mclapply`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it using `sapply` and `lapply`.

```
recordAttribs <- xpathSApply(doc=xml, path="//HealthData/Record",  xmlAttrs)

recordAttribs <- t(recordAttribs)
```

Get a vector of `TRUE/FALSE` using `sapply` based on whether elements in your list are equal to 7.

```
short.condition <- sapply(recordAttribs, function(x) length(x)==7)
```

Use `lapply` on a subset of your list that meets this condition. This time you are concatenating two `NA` within the vectors that meet the above condition:

```
recordAttribs[short.condition] <- lapply(recordAttribs, 
                                         function(x) c(x[1:2],NA,NA,x[3:7]))
```

To convert this to a data.frame in the form you want:

```
df <- matrix(unlist(recordAttribs),
            nrow=2,ncol=9, byrow=TRUE)

df <- data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

names(df) <- c("type","sourceName","sourceVersion","device","unit","creationDate","startDate","endDate","value")
```

Which looks like this:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ type         : chr  "HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount" "HKQuantityTypeIdentifierFlightsClimbed"
 $ sourceName   : chr  "Ryan Praskievicz iPhone" "Ryan Praskievicz iPhone"
 $ sourceVersion: chr  NA "9.3.2"
 $ device       : chr  NA "<<HKDevice: 0x15a4af3f0>, name:iPhone, manufacturer:Apple, model:iPhone, hardware:iPhone8,1, software:9.3.2>"
 $ unit         : chr  "count" "count"
 $ creationDate : chr  "2014-10-02 08:30:17 -0400" "2016-06-02 12:27:46 -0400"
 $ startDate    : chr  "2014-09-24 15:07:06 -0400" "2016-06-02 12:09:29 -0400"
 $ endDate      : chr  "2014-09-24 15:07:11 -0400" "2016-06-02 12:09:29 -0400"
 $ value        : chr  "7" "1"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but this is not exactly what I am looking for. I want the data in a data frame like the first table in my question under "I want the data in a data frame like this."

Comment: @RyanPraskievicz I edited my answer to account for this. It's not the prettiest solution. I'm assuming the same two columns are going to be missing for your observations with 7 rows.

Comment: @RyanPraskievicz made one more edit to put the output into a useful data.frame.